# Reference problems in .Net Core - Serialization and NetworkInterface for example

Tags: .net-core

In my exploration of creating applications using .NetCore I have come across two classes of reference problems, one I was able to work through, one not quite yet..

The current problem I am having is that after referencing a nuget package that provides certain classes, I'm not always able to use those classes. If it were only one or two classes, I might assume a documentation or not yet implemented type of issue. Since I am using RC1 Update 1, I would think that to be pretty rare.

As an example, I want to use the System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface class. The package System.Net.NetworkInformation nuget package (4.1.0-Beta23516) claims to provide that class, and the .Net Portability report didn't report any problems using said class, so I have reason to believe this should work.

I have similar problems with all of the XML Serialization attributes too, so it isn't isolated to just this class or package.

Another problem I was experiencing (in case this helps anybody else) is that after adding certain packages, such as System.Threading, the project.json file listed the package as a dependency of all frameworks, resulting in the .Net Framework 4.5.1 configuration as having two System.Threading.Thread classes. Moving the dependency to the dotnet5.4 dependencies was an easy fix (once I figured out the problem)